# Swift 3, in Poloniex trade Api get - "error": Invalid command

Tags: swift, alamofire, poloniex

My code:

```
func testApi() {
        Alamofire.request("https://www.poloniex.com/tradingApi", withMethod: .post, parameters: ["command":"returnDepositAddresses","nonce":nonce()], encoding: .json, headers: ["Key":apiKey,"Sign":newSecret]).responseJSON() { (dataBack) in
            print(dataBack)
        }
    }
func nonce() -> Int {
        let date = "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970)"
        let UnixInt = Double(date)!
        return Int(UnixInt)
    }
```

And I get it:

```
SUCCESS: {
error = "Invalid command.";}
```

I can't find any info about poloniex api with Swift or Objective C... 
So if somebody can help - I'll be very grateful

Comment: Are you sure '["error": Invalid command.]' comes from that exact print line?

Comment: @pedrouan Yes. I was remove "print" commands when write this topic. But already edit it.

Comment: Well. the error is not related to the API, as the response appears correct. Please append this line right after your 'print(dataBack.response)' line: `print(dataBack)`

Comment: @pedrouan ok, I add it. `Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x600000031020> { URL: https://www.poloniex.com/tradingApi } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = private;
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Mon, 05 Sep 2016 05:11:34 GMT";
    Server = "cloudflare-nginx";
    "cf-ray" = "2dd72e64b2dc30e4-SIN";
} })
SUCCESS: {
    error = "Invalid command.";
}
SUCCESS`

Comment: I think something wrong with parameters maybe... Because if I change it for ["command":"anything"] - it will be same error.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to form your `NSURLRequest` for `poloniex.com`.

Imagine that your:

1. `API Key` = @"apikey"
2. `Secret` = @"secret"
3. `nonce` = @"1"

Starting with the simplest things:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *theURLRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest new];
theURLRequest.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://poloniex.com/tradingApi"];
theURLRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSString *theBodyString = @"command=returnBalances&nonce=1";

theURLRequest.HTTPBody = [theBodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[theURLRequest setValue:@"apikey" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Key"];
```

And now the hardest bit...

As to me, Poloniex documentation wasn't very clear on what they want under the `"Sign"` header field value, but basically they want you to pass a string, which should be a result of `HMAC SHA512` encryption algorithm applied to both `theBodyString` **and** `Secret` (which in our example is simply @"secret").

Here is the function which would return you the `HMAC SHA512` `NSData`:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>
NSData * getHMACSHA512FromSecretKeyStringAndBodyString(NSString *theSecretKeyString, NSString *theBodyString)
{
    const char *cSecret  = [theSecretKeyString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    const char *cBody = [theBodyString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA512, cSecret, strlen(cSecret), cBody, strlen(cBody), cHMAC);
    return [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
}
```

So, running:

```
NSData *theData = getHMACSHA512FromSecretKeyStringAndBodyString(@"secret", @"command=returnBalances&nonce=1");
NSString *theString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", theData];
```

Would give us **almost** what we wanted.

Our result is equal to:

```
<c288f881 a6808d0e 78827ec6 ca9d6b9c 34ec1667 07716303 0d6d7abb 2b225456 31176f52 8347ab0f d6671ec5 3aec1f7d 3b6de8b8 e3ccc23d e62fd594 52d70db5>
```

While what we actually want (as per http://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html) is:

```
c288f881a6808d0e78827ec6ca9d6b9c34ec1667077163030d6d7abb2b22545631176f528347ab0fd6671ec53aec1f7d3b6de8b8e3ccc23de62fd59452d70db5
```

So, basically, just remove the `<`, `>` and  symbols from your string;

```
theString = [theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
theString = [theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
theString = [theString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
[theURLRequest setValue:theString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Sign"];
```

Your `theURLRequest` is now ready and should succeed getting the `tradingApi` of `poloniex.com`.

Comment: This is great! You got it perfectly right and this helped me a lot. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's neither Swift nor iOS issue. 
It's because you are accessing Trading API methods, and they may require some more additional parameters (except of nonce) in your POST request:

Check this:

> All calls to the trading API are sent via HTTP POST to
>   https://poloniex.com/tradingApi and must contain the following
>   headers:
>
> Key - Your API key. Sign - The query's POST data signed by your key's
>   "secret" according to the HMAC-SHA512 method. Additionally, all
>   queries must include a "nonce" POST parameter. The nonce parameter is
>   an integer which must always be greater than the previous nonce used.

Thus:

> All responses from the trading API are in JSON format. In the event of
>   an error, the response will always be of the following format:
>
> {"error":""}

https://temp.poloniex.com/support/api/

Comment: I already add headers key and Sign code (when this wrong - I get "error:Invalid key or Sign code") 
So I can't understand what command is invalid

Comment: I mean, key and sign is right for sure. 
It is API or request error. And my topic here for resolve this error. If his possible...

Comment: OK I haven't understood your previous comment, it looked you have problem with sign code. Have you passed any previous commands before? Or this is the first you have run? And try this `set the "account" POST parameter to "all"`

Comment: Now key and sign is right. When I was write wrong key - I was get "error = "Invalid API key/secret pair." And now I resolve this problem. But second problem(reason why I create this topic) - is "error = "Invalid command." I want to understand what I have to do now with this...

I try with many different parameters, but get same error. In java example code, they use just "returnBalances" without any extra command or parameters...

Comment: Yes. But if I use "command":"returnDepositAddresses" - I get same error. 
If I use "hello":"hello" - I get same error... 
For any parameters I get same error.

Comment: In this case I cannot help as it relates to your secret login data. You say, your java request are working properly? Doesn't it require any additional header or something?

Comment: For exemple simple python request:
`urllib2.Request('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', post_data, headers)`
 where post data is: `req['command'] = 'returnDepositAddresses'
            req['nonce'] = int(time.time()*1000)` and headers is: `headers = {
                'Sign': sign,
                'Key': self.APIKey
            }` thats all what it need for correct request...

Comment: Try to `print(self.APIKey)` and `print(sign)` as well right before Almofire.request line. Don't post it, just check whether they are there.